# Compact set between open and compact sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'd like to verify if my proof for this problem from Spivak's Calculus on a manifold makes sense:

1-22. If $U$ open and $C\subset U$ is compact, show that there is a compact set $D$ such that $C\subset {\rm int} \ D$ and $D\subset U$.

Proof: $U$ is open implies that $U^c$ is closed and $U^c \cap C=\emptyset$, also since $C$ is compact, by result from 1-21, there exists $d>0$ such that  $|y-x|\geq d$ for all $y\in U^c$ and $x\in C$.  Now take $D=\overline{C\cup (\bigcup_{x\in \partial C} U_x)}$ where $U_x$ is the open rectangle of side length $d/2$ centered at $x$. By construction, $C\subset {\rm int}\ D$. Also since all $\overline{U_x}\in U$, we have $D\subset U$. Finally, $D$ is bounded and closed, so $D$ is compact.

Note: I've learned point-set topology before reading Spivak's book, but in this case I just want to find a simple proof based on the limited definitions Spivak has provided without recourse to topology.

Comment: What is the space we are considering? A metric space? A subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, since this is first chapter of multivariable calculus

Comment: If $C$ is compact then $C$ is closed so $\partial C=\overline C\cap \overline {\Bbb R^n\setminus C}\subset \overline C\subset C$....  So why not take $E=\cup_{x\in C}U_x $ and $D=\overline E$. Then $C\subset E \subset$ int $D.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yeah that’s a good point. When I wrote this down my intuition is just to “expand” along the boundary, and I didn’t really go to write down how to derive that boundary by set operations, which Spivak does not mention in his book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a minor flaw in your proof: if $U_x$ is an open rectangle of side length $\frac{d}{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the distance from its center $x$ to a corner is $\frac{d}{4} \sqrt{n}$, which for large enough $n$ will be greater than $d$.  In that case you can no longer conclude that $U_x \subset U$.

This is easily fixed by letting $U_x$ be an open ball of radius $\frac{d}{2}$ instead of a rectangle.

Otherwise the proof looks fine.

Comment: Ah, thank you for pointing out this flaw!